# How to detect in JavaScript if request made in getTileUrl (Google Maps) was successful or not?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to the community,
I have a simple google Map overlay, I get the tiles (format png) from an external service, example: https://example.tiles.com/
I need to monitor or some mechanism in JavaScript to track or detect successful, failed requests made by `getTileUrl` to the external service, I have searched the official documentation and found nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <style> 
    #map { 
        width: 600px; 
        height: 500px; 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        let gmap;
        function initMap() {
            gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 44.9648, lng: -93.252},
                zoom: 5
            });

            const layers = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                    return ['https://example.tiles.com/', zoom, '/', coord.x, '/', coord.y, '/current.png'].join('');
                },
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
            });
            gmap.overlayMapTypes.push(layers);
        };
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried with the `tilesloaded` listener but it does not support function arguments.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(gmap, 'tilesloaded', function(){
..
});
```

[tilesloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MojTP.jpg)

What is wanted is simply to count the successful requests made to https://example.tiles.com/ by `getTileUrl`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to send an alert when the map loads?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not support parameters"?

Comment: - What is wanted is simply to count the successful requests made to https://example.tiles.com/ by getTileUrl, I mean that the tilesloaded event does not support arguments.

Comment: It's because it gets triggered when the Maps Javascript tiles gets loaded. Not the example.tiles.com.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the `'tilesloaded'` and it worked for me using this:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(gmap, 'tilesloaded', function(){
alert("Tile is loaded!")
});
```

I just changed the first parameter `map` into `gmap` because that's how you defined the map instance on your code.

Here's a snippet for you to check if this is how you want it to happen:

```js
let gmap;
function initMap() {
  gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 44.9648, lng: -93.252},
    zoom: 5
  });

  const layers = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return ['https://example.tiles.com/', zoom, '/', coord.x, '/', coord.y, '/current.png'].join('');
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
  });
  gmap.overlayMapTypes.push(layers);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(gmap, 'tilesloaded', function(){
    alert("Tile is loaded!")
  });
};
```

```css
#map { 
  width: 600px; 
  height: 500px; 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What happens here is when the `tilesloaded` is triggered, it will send an alert with text `"Tile is Loaded!"`.

Hope this helps.